# Recurring Hangfire job runs only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I have the problem that scheduled Hangfire jobs that should be carried out every day are switched off as soon as I close the local host.

This is my Code in the HomeController:

```
public void  TriggerFunction()
        {
 
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Update(), Cron.Daily());
          
        }
```

If I execute `localhost/Home/TriggerFunction` and then `localhost/Hangfire` I can see the jobs in the Hangfire overview.
As soon as I run the project again and go only to `localhost/Hangfire` it says: no jobs

Comment: How do you setup the `hangfire`? Are you using a database?

Comment: yes Sql-Server and I added all services in Startup

Comment: Try to replace your job with this `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Test"), "* * * * *");` or with the similar Cron Expression to help you debug better. is the job running either the problem is on the UI?

Comment: I changed, but the same..... the problem is that the job is not saved. When I run my project and go to Hangfire there is no job

Comment: You should add more information. Do you follow the instructions https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html correctly?

Comment: Yes I did everything

Comment: Do u see any jobs under recurring tab? And what do you mean by close out of local host?

Comment: when I close localhost - when I close the page and run again my project, there is no recurring jobs